# How to insert a value from an input in a specific row and column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help.

I have a dataframe , like :

```
A B C D
1 2 3 
5 6 7 
5 7 5
```

And I would like with python to get the D values from an input:

for example

```
for i in df.iterlupes():
    d= input(" put the number:")
    df["d"] = d
```

and then for example I will input 1 2 3  , I will have:

```
A B C D
1 2 3 1
5 6 7 2
5 7 5 3
```

How can I do that please ? Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Please post some example starting data, as well as what you expect the df to look like after.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're asking though I have no idea what `.interlupes()` is supposed to mean.

What you want to do is relatively simple, you want to capture user inputs and place them into a location in the dataframe. What you have not made clear is how you are capturing where to put them.

In your example here is what you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,5,5],"B":[2,6,7],"C":[3,7,5]})

def enter_new_column(df, name, print_column):

    # loop over length of the rows
    temp_arr = []
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        temp_arr.append(input(f"Put the Number for the value {df[print_column][i]}: "))
    df[name] = temp_arr

enter_new_column(df=df, name="D", print_column="Intitulé_complet")
```

Comment: you can mark my question as an answer if this is what you wanted

Comment: Could you just tell me how to tell put the number for 1: (A 0) ? whether that row i

Comment: Sorry could you please rephrase that I'm not sure I unerstand what you mean "the number for 1: (A 0)".

Comment: f"Put the number " + df.loc[i, 'A']

Comment: Whether than print the row i , ask to put a number for the number in the column A

Comment: .loc only takes in the names of rows/columns, use .iloc[] to pass integer values representing the index of the column/row.

Comment: I've done def enter_new_column(df, name):

    # loop over length of the rows
    temp_arr = []
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        d= input("La quantité du produit pour " + " " + df.at[i, 'Intitulé_complet'] + " : ")
        
        temp_arr.append(d)
    df[name] = temp_arr

enter_new_column(df=devis, name="Quantité") , but I've this error : KeyError: 1

Comment: I see what you're saying but I don't see how that makes sense. You want it to print the column? Can you explain what  'Intitulé_complet' is? Is it a column? But then what is "Quantité"? In my approach "Quantité" is the new column, so why would I print an other unrelated column. I'll edit my code to allow you to print an arbitrary column, but I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Thanks ! That's exatcly what I need, I worked, but when I put the number I get this error (from Kaggle): KeyError: 1 , Intitulé_Complet is a name of column, so I wanna input a number by knowing wich "Intitul_complet" I'm refering

Comment: @MartinELIAS In this case  you can see that the column D doesn't exist and he added a new one , par contre  if you want to change the values of the clumn that already exists I doubt his code will work.

Comment: I've got: key Error 1

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are searching for :

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 5, 5], 
                   "B":[2, 6, 7],  
                   "C":[3, 7, 5], 
                   "D":[" "]*3})
print (df)
for e in range (3):
    d= input(" put the number:")
    df.at[e,'D']=d
print (df)
```

Output is :

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3   
1  5  6  7   
2  5  7  5   
 put the number:1
 put the number:2
 put the number:3
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  1
1  5  6  7  2
2  5  7  5  3
```

Final Code for your example (based on the comment) :

```
def enter_new_column(df, name): 
    for e in range (df.shape[0]):
        d= input(" put the number: ")
        df.at[e,name]=d
        
enter_new_column(devis, "Quantité")
```

Comment: Hi thanks !! Do you know how to do that : put the number for 1 ( that is a value in column A) , and then the next , put the number for 5

Comment: @MartinELIAS can you rephrase your question ?

Comment: @MartinELIAS to put the values in the specified places  you can look at the first line of my code  that is `df = pd.Dataframe....`  there you can set the value of the row A, B, C and D and if you want to set the value of `(A,0)` to be 1 you just put 1 as the first element of the array after `"A":`

Comment: @MartinELIAS J'esp_re que ca marche maintenant.

Comment: Donne moi ton email :)